# Prevent content locker bypassing

Tags: javascript, php, html

I recently made a giveaway site, to join the giveaway you have to complete a content locker.

After you complete the locker a POST request is made to a page called (e.g) action_join.php, and let's say that the data of the POST request is the username and the email.

Anyone could complete the locker just one time, see how the POST request is made (using developer tools), and then generate a new POST request (using a tool or a programming language) without completing the locker.

And that's even worse than that because if he posts the request details on the internet, everyone could generate the same request (with different data) and all of them would join the giveaway without even completing the locker once.

So i was wondering if there was a way to prevent people from doing that by implementing some kind of protection that can detect if the locker has really been completed or not (or anything else that can prevent this).

Am i right?
Does anyone have an idea on how to prevent this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Determine if the locker has been completed **server-side**.

Comment: And how can i determine if the locker has really been completed? It's a locker taken from a CPA Network so all i can do is set some JS to be executed after the locker has been completed.

Comment: We'd have to know much more about your setup, but fundamentally: If the information is available client-side, then it will not remain private. So the answer is: The information shouldn't be available client-side.